# Can I install Netbeans while I already installed jdk.1.6.xx on same machine?

Tags: windows-vista, installation, java

I just about to learn Java programming. I already have jdk on my computer. Then, I found this Netbeans is quite popular and come with all I needs. My question is, will there be any conflict if I install full version of Netbeans while I already have jdk installed on same machine(windows vista)?

I will appreciate your answers and advices, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans is an IDE for many programming languages. There is no issue of installing Netbeans after installing java sdk. For details follow http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html

> JDK 6 or JDK 5 is required for
>   installing and running the Java SE,
>   JavaFX, Java and All NetBeans Bundles.
>   You can download standalone JDK  or
>   download the latest JDK with NetBeans
>   IDE Java SE bundle.

Answer (score 1):

No,
Why would there be any conflict? It will just install smooth and fine. You may install it without worrying about anything.

Answer (score -1):

As Nitesh says,their will be no conflict but if the installer could not find your jdk path , you have to specify manualy.